# Browser is not being loaded

Tags: android

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser_detail);
  Bundle browserDetailBundle =  getIntent().getExtras();
  if(browserDetailBundle!= null)
  {
    detailsToBrowse = browserDetailBundle.getString("EditTextContent");
    if (!detailsToBrowse.startsWith("http://") && !detailsToBrowse.startsWith("https://"))
      detailsToBrowse = "http://" + detailsToBrowse;    
    viewToBrowse = (View)findViewById(R.id.editTextBrowser);
  }
  callMe(viewToBrowse);
}

public void callMe(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(detailsToBrowse));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: What you're trying to do there? Are trying to load the browser as soon it enters on this activity? Or `callMe(View v)` is supposed to be an event of a button?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, yours `detailsToBrowse` begins with "`http://`" or "`https://`"

```
if (!detailsToBrowse.startsWith("http://") && !detailsToBrowse.startsWith("https://"))
    detailsToBrowse = "http://" + detailsToBrowse;
```

And change your method

```
public void callMe(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(detailsToBrowse);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: still the issue isn't fixed

Comment: @manisharma have you checked about the string beginning with http://? So far as I know, the error that you posted happens when you're missing it...

Comment: i did sir, but the issue sustained eventually i made the intent final and that worked fine :) by the way thatnks for your concern